# File upload in Spring

Tags: spring, multipart

I am trying to upload an audio file using the following code on server.Right now, it works perfectly well for image files but not for audios.I think MultipartFile should work with audio files as well.Can any one tell me what is wrong here?
I am getting "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method." error.

Does MultipartFile not work with audio files?If no what is an alternative?

```
@Transactional
public BaseVO uploadImage(MultipartFile file, long userId){
    Map<String, Object> alertParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    try{
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            Image profileImage = imageRepository.findByUserId(userId);
            if(profileImage == null){
                profileImage = new Image();
                profileImage.setUserId(userId);
            }

            File dir = null;
            String realPath;
            if(liveBuild == "true"){
                realPath = liveImageUploadRepository;
                dir = new File(realPath);
            }else{
                HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
                realPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + devImageUploadRepository;
                dir = new File(realPath);
            }
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            String finalFileStorePath = realPath + "/" + userId + ".jpg";
            File path = new File(finalFileStorePath);
            file.transferTo(path);

            profileImage.setImagePath(realPath);
            //profileImage.setImageName(userId + ".jpg");
            profileImage.setImageName(userId+"");
            profileImage.setImageType(".jpg");

            imageRepository.save(profileImage);

            alertParams.put("id", profileImage.getId());
        } else {
            return new BaseVO(alertParams, Constants.STATUS_OK, Constants.STATUS_OK_MSG);
        }
    }catch(HibernateException e){
        return new BaseVO(alertParams, Constants.STATUS_ERROR, Constants.STATUS_ERROR_MSG + " " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new BaseVO(alertParams, Constants.STATUS_ERROR, Constants.STATUS_ERROR_MSG);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new BaseVO(alertParams, Constants.STATUS_ERROR, Constants.STATUS_ERROR_MSG);
    }
    return new BaseVO(alertParams, Constants.STATUS_OK, Constants.STATUS_OK_MSG);
}
```

Comment: Is there any stacktrace server side to help understand what happens ? Anyway, I can see that server code tries to build a thumbnail and I do not think it can convert a audio file to a thumbnail ...

Comment: oh i forgot commenting that thumbnail part.But even without it, it is not working

Comment: And for the stacktrace ?

Comment: I was asking for a possible stacktrace server side, something saying what exceptions were thrown in what module and at what line. It is the base for understanding java errors.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: src cannot be null
 org.imgscalr.Scalr.resize(Scalr.java:1564)
 com.alertcall.service.ImageService.uploadImage(ImageService.java:111)

Comment: The error comes in a part that you did not show. What is line 111 of ImageService.java ?